# Is there a way to show/open a file from a URI/URL

Tags: find-file, url

Is there some way to download and show a file from a URI/URL?

I now I can use `wget` and then open the downloaded file and I guess I could even try to write myself a small function to do this.

But most likely someone did before me so is there a function/package that will let me get a file from the internets (would be great if it did not save the file somewhere first) and open it in a new buffer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
M-x url-handler-mode
C-x C-f http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21180/is-there-a-way-to-show-open-a-file-from-a-uri-url
```

This opens the HTML file of this stackexchange question in your Emacs.

Comment: yes nice - is there a way to combine this into a single command so I don't have to change the mode of some random buffer first?

Comment: `url-handler-mode` is a *global minor mode*, not a major mode. Just put `(url-handler-mode 1)` into your init file.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the file "rendered", you can use the web browser eww - just do `M-x eww RET url RET`

Answer (score 2):

You can turn URLs  in a buffer into clickable buttons with Emacs **goto-address-mode** minor mode.  If the URL represents a web page, then you can get Emacs to browse that page by clicking on the URL button.

Turn this mode on/off with: `M-x goto-address-mode`

This works with Emacs running in Graphics mode and in terminal mode.  A special key map is activated when point is over the URL button.  The `C-c RET` key sequence is bound to **goto-address-at-point** which makes Emacs browse the web page.

It's also possible to add key binding to that special map.  In my system I added keys to navigate to the next or previous URL and to copy he content of the file identified by the URL into a local temporary file  and then visit it.  To do that  add a function to the goto-address-mode-hook that maps commands into the `goto-address-highlight-keymap`.